# how to display exact line number (where the error has occured) in logging library

Tags: python, logging, exception, error-logging

In the following code, the error is at line 7. However, log displays error at line 10, where logging is mentioned.

```
import logging
import urllib2
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname) -10s %(asctime)s %(module)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)s %(message)s')
def main():
    try:
        urls = "http://www.simplyhired.com/a/job-detaw/jobkey-67b4efe169eee7b2cf2ed47d49b1845070ea37/rid-racliggzfyjgqwfzrlvnqyjtcserhrri/cjp-3/pub_id-1002"
        site = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
        mathfail = 1/0
    except Exception, e:
        logging.critical(str(e))

main()
```

Following is displayed in log:

```
CRITICAL   2016-04-08 15:28:47,063 testt:10 main HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I want it to display line number where the error has occured and not the line number where logging is mentioned. It should display line 7 and not line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives me the expected output:

```
import logging
import urllib2
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname) -10s %(asctime)s %(module)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)s %(message)s')
def main():
    try:
        urls = "http://www.simplyhired.com/a/job-detaw/jobkey-67b4efe169eee7b2cf2ed47d49b1845070ea37/rid-racliggzfyjgqwfzrlvnqyjtcserhrri/cjp-3/pub_id-1002"
        site = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
        mathfail = 1/0
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(str(e))

main()
```

output in the log file is:

```
ERROR      2016-04-08 16:18:35,430 testt:10 main HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testt.py", line 7, in main
    site = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
  File "/home/deepu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/deepu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/deepu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/deepu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/deepu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/deepu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for stack track

```
import logging
import urllib2
import traceback
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname) -10s %(asctime)s %(module)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)s %(message)s')
def main():
    try:
        urls = "http://www.simplyhired.com/a/job-detaw/jobkey-67b4efe169eee7b2cf2ed47d49b1845070ea37/rid-racliggzfyjgqwfzrlvnqyjtcserhrri/cjp-3/pub_id-1002"
        site = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
        mathfail = 1/0
    except Exception:
        logging.critical(traceback.format_exc())

main()
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. It has to be log.

Comment: @dsl1990 you can change it to logging.critical(traceback.format_exc())